# How to get geom_boxplot to change colors for groups in a time series?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot get `geom_boxplot` to display both of my groups (`Location`) for each `Date` in a time series.

Example Data:

```
set.seed(321)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 18))
colnames(dat)[1:3] <- c("Date","Location","Value")
dat$Value <- round(rnorm(18, 100,50),0)
dat$Location <- rep(c("Location 1","Location 2"), each = 9)
st <- as.Date("2022-05-15")
en <- as.Date("2022-07-15")
dat$Date <- rep(seq.Date(st,en,by = '1 month'),6)
str(dat)
```

This shows each group (`Location`) however it does not provide a boxplot for each `Date`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill = Location)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")
```

This provides a boxplot for each date but it does not show each group

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill = Location)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = Date)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")
```

The ideal figure would have a boxplot for each `Date` and each `Location`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `interaction(Date, Location)` to get the type of plot you're after:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill = Location, group = interaction(Date, Location))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `facet_wrap`:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat %>% 
  mutate(Date_wrap = format(as.Date(Date), "%Y-%m")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes (y = Value, fill = Location)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ Date_wrap, scales = "free", strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

[image]